# Why does dict.get(key) run slower than dict[key]

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

While running a numerical integrator, I noticed a noticeable difference in speed depending on how I extract the value of the field in a dictionary

```
import numpy as np

def bad_get(mydict):
    '''Extract the name field using get()'''
    output = mydict.get('name', None)
    return output

def good_get(mydict):
    '''Extract the name field using if-else'''
    if 'name' in mydict:
        output = mydict['name']
    else:
        output = None
    return output


name_dict = dict()
name_dict['name'] = np.zeros((5000,5000))
```

On my system, I notice the following difference (using iPython)

```
%%timeit
bad_get(name_dict) 

The slowest run took 7.75 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 247 ns per loop
```

Compared to

```
%%timeit
good_get(name_dict)  

1000000 loops, best of 3: 188 ns per loop
```

This may seem like a small difference, but in for some arrays the difference appears to be even more dramatic. What causes this behavior, and is there some way I should alter my use of the `get()` function?

Comment: Good observation. If you hunt for speed, you can replace `mydict.get("name")` to `mydict["name"]` in try/except block, catching `KeyError` and assigning `None` there.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Python has to do more work for `dict.get()`:

- `get` is an attribute, so Python has to look this up, and then bind the descriptor found to the dictionary instance.
- `()` is a call, so the current frame has to be pushed on the stack, a call has to be made, then the frame has to be popped again from the stack to continue.

The `[...]` notation, used with a `dict`, doesn't require a separate attribute step or frame push and pop.

You can see the difference when you use the [Python bytecode disassembler `dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('d[key]', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (d)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (key)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
              7 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile('d.get(key)', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (d)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (get)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (key)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

so the `d[key]` expression only has to execute a `BINARY_SUBSCR` opcode, while `d.get(key)` adds a `LOAD_ATTR` opcode. `CALL_FUNCTION` is a lot more expensive than `BINARY_SUBSCR` on a built-in type (custom types with `__getitem__` methods still end up doing a function call).

If the *majority* of your keys exist in the dictionary, you could use `try...except KeyError` to handle missing keys:

```
try:
    return mydict['name']
except KeyError:
    return None
```

Exception handling is cheap if there are no exceptions.

Comment: Why can't we upvote and upvote again such good answers .. appreciate the time you spent in explaining the issue with great knowledge .. :)

Comment: A speed test of an extra 'try' would be also useful, compared to the good_get.