# Why is max() function so much slower when comparing 2 elements vs direct comparison with an if statement?

Tags: python, max

By running the below code I get for direct comparison with an if statement almost 4x the speed vs using the max function.

I am trying to understand the reason behind this.

comparison : 0.63s, max : 2.3s

```
import time

if _name_ == '_main_':
    sim = 10**7

    s = time.time()
    for _ in range(sim):
        if 1 > 2:
            pass
    res1 = time.time()-s

    s = time.time()
    for _ in range(sim):
        max(1, 2)
    res2 = time.time()-s

    print('comparison : {:.2}s, max : {:.2}s'.format(res1, res2))
```

Comment: Interestingly, pylint suggests to use the latter (`max()` function): `https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/refactor/consider-using-max-builtin.html`

Comment: Consider using timeit module for benchmarking code. No need to manually calculate diff of `time.time()`. E.g. `timeit.timeit('if 1>2: pass')` vs `timeit.timeit('max(1,2)')`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

because `max` involves a dictionary lookup for the function name, then a function call, whereas direct `<` operator does not.

`max` is beginning to become interesting speed-wise when you have more elements.

Related / same speed difference:

- [Why does dict.get(key) run slower than dict[key]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566331/why-does-dict-getkey-run-slower-than-dictkey)
- [Why is [] faster than list()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list)

Comment: Two dictionary lookups actually; one in module globals, and when that fails, a second one in builtin scope. If you're calling `max` a lot in a given function, caching it (e.g. via a keyword only argument, a la `def myfunc(arg1, arg2, *, max=max):`) is a cheap hack to remove the lookup costs (replacing the two `dict` lookups of `LOAD_GLOBAL` with a single C array indexing operation from `LOAD_FAST`). The function call overhead is the larger cost though (generic function dispatch has a lot more overhead than anything that goes straight for specialized slotted functions, e.g. `<`).

Comment: yes, dictionary lookup is `O(1)`. Thanks for the precisions though, interesting.

Comment: Well, it's all basically `O(1)` (aside from "how many items were passed to `max`). `dict` lookup is `O(1)` average case, but with a higher constant overhead than arrays and frequently one or two bucket collisions before it finds the right item. On my machine, a function that loads, but doesn't call, `max` 1000 times takes about 45 μs to run without caching in the arguments, about 25.5 μs with the `max=max` caching, and 21.5 μs if the 1000 long loop body is `pass` instead of `max`. So loading from the local 1000x costs ~4 μs, loading from builtin scope cost ~23.5 μs, nearly 6x higher overhead.

Comment: Though like I said, that overhead pales in comparison to actually calling it (having it call `max(1, 2)` increases time to 206 μs uncached, and 173 μs, so the benefit of caching is dwarfed by the overhead of calling the function).

Comment: now my answer feels undocumented :) Also `O(1)` doesn't mean that it isn't costly for super-long function names because hashing takes longer to compute (not the case for `max`, though). If you want speed, use a compiled language, or a framework like numpy or pandas where you pass one request for a lot of data, not small requests.

Comment: that also reminds me of `a <= b < c` versus `b in range(a,c)`

Comment: Well, ultra-detailed now, but CPython (and I'd assume most alternate interpreters, because it makes sense) interns all names during compilation, which also precomputes & caches the hash codes, so the name length doesn't matter for hashing. And being interned in all the `dict`s, the comparison operation ends up being identity based (assuming you haven't manually inserted an uninterned `str` into the `dict`s that implement globals and builtins), so the contents of the string are never actually read for comparison. And yeah, range testing is definitely similar to this case.

Comment: all this information in comments seems wasteful to me (because comments, are, you know, comments and can be easily discarded). Would be better in a real answer (even if OP didn't ask that much detail). Thanks, very instructive anyway