# Add +1 to value at index i if less or equals to previous index, else do nothing

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to optimize this code using numpy built-in function:

```
result = [test[0]]
for x in range(1, len(test)):
    if test[x] <= result[-1]:
        result.append(result[-1]+1)
    else:
        result.append(test[x])
print(result)
```

The above code loops through the array, checks if the previous value is equal or superior to the current value, and if it is, adds +1. Otherwise, it does nothing.

It is recursive (the current value depends on the previously calculated value).

With `test = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17])` I expect to get `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

Is there a better way of doing this? I need to use this many times with very big arrays (>=10M length.

Comment: Can you share more information/statistics about the arrays in question? For example, what is the largest value in the array compared to the length (i.e. `max(test)` vs `len(test)`)? Depending on structure, you may be able to write faster algorithms that take advantage the structure.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested different approaches following Onyambu comment:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit
import itertools


# Original loop-based version
def adjust_array_if(test):
    result = [test[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(test)):
        if test[i] <= result[-1]:
            result.append(result[-1]+1)
        else:
            result.append(test[i])
    return np.array(result)

# Max loop-based version
def adjust_array_max(test):
    result = [test[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(test)):
        result.append(max(test[i], result[-1] + 1))
    return np.array(result)

# Version using itertools
def adjust_array_itertools(test):
    result = np.fromiter(itertools.accumulate(test, lambda x, y: max(x + 1, y)), dtype=np.int32)
    return result

# Set up the DataFrame
functions = pd.Index(['adjust_array_if', 'adjust_array_max', 'adjust_array_itertools'], name='function')
lengths = np.arange(100, 11000, 1000)
results = pd.DataFrame(index=lengths, columns=functions)

# Time the functions
for i in lengths:
    a = np.random.randint(1, i, size=i)
    for j in functions:
        stmt = f"{j}(a)"
        setup = f"from __main__ import {j}, a"
        timing = timeit(stmt, setup, number=10)
        results.at[i, j] = timing

# Plot the results
results.plot()
```

with the following results:
[image]

Simpler is better in that case?

Comment: In your question you said *"My input array is, by design, always sorted"*, but your input arrays here aren't.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. However, the logic still is the same, i should remove this information

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
import numpy as np

def adjust_array(test):
    result = [test[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(test)):
        result.append(max(test[i], result[-1] + 1))
    return np.array(result)

# Test the function
test = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17])
result = adjust_array(test)
print(result)
```

This ensures that each element in the result array is strictly greater than the previous one if the corresponding element in the input array is not greater.

Output:

```
>>> [ 0  1  2  3  4 15 16 17 18 19]
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb for not thinking about using the max function !

Comment: @Yop The `if else` statement you provided is better than the `max` option given. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281691/why-is-max-function-so-much-slower-when-comparing-2-elements-vs-direct-compari

Answer (score 0):

Some faster solutions based on your original, using your answer's benchmark:

[image: benchmark plot]

The first one solely adds `test = test.tolist()` at the start. Because Python works faster on its own ints than on NumPy ints. The other two additionally avoid indexing and use a list comprehension.

```
def adjust_array_Kelly(test):
    test = test.tolist()
    result = [test[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(test)):
        if test[i] <= result[-1]:
            result.append(result[-1]+1)
        else:
            result.append(test[i])
    return np.array(result)

def adjust_array_Kelly2(test):
    last = float('-inf')
    return np.array([
        last := last + 1 if last >= t else t
        for t in test.tolist()
    ])

def adjust_array_Kelly3(test):
    return np.array([
        last
        for last in [float('-inf')]
        for t in test.tolist()
        for last in [last + 1 if last >= t else t]
    ])
```