# Why is key in dict() faster than dict.get(key) in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to check whether a key exists in a dictionary. The most appropriate way, as per my knowledge is:
`if d_.get(s):`. But, while attempting a question on Leetcode, there was a TLE error when I was using this method. However, when I tried `if s in d_`, TLE was gone. I want to know why `in` is faster than `get()`.

I tried going through some questions, found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566331/why-does-dict-getkey-run-slower-than-dictkey) where there is an explanation for `d_.get()` v/s `d_[s]`. None of the questions addressed `d_.get()` v/s `s in d_`.

Just in case, some context:

The code that failed with `if self.memo.get(s):`:

```
from typing import List


class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word_dict = {}
        self.memo = {}

    def word_break(self, s):
        if not s:
            return True
        if self.memo.get(s):
            return self.memo[s]
        res = False
        for word in self.word_dict.keys():
            if len(word) <= len(s) and s[:len(word)] == word:
                res = res or self.word_break(s[len(word):])
                self.memo[s] = res
        return res

    def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
        for word in wordDict:
            self.word_dict[word] = 1
        return(self.word_break(s))
```

The code than got accepted with `if s in self.memo`:

```
from typing import List


class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word_dict = {}
        self.memo = {}

    def word_break(self, s):
        if not s:
            return True
        if s in self.memo:
            return self.memo[s]
        res = False
        for word in self.word_dict.keys():
            if len(word) <= len(s) and s[:len(word)] == word:
                res = res or self.word_break(s[len(word):])
                self.memo[s] = res
        return res

    def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
        for word in wordDict:
            self.word_dict[word] = 1
        return(self.word_break(s))
```

I always presumed that `in` would be slower than fetching attributes(here, `get()`).

Comment: [You're free to look at the C source code yourself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c) - I'm too lazy right now - but I would assume it's because `in` just looks to see if a value exists in the hashtable, whereas `.get()` has to do the additional overhead of actually retrieving that value and allocating temporary memory for it.

Comment: Dictionaries are indexed by their keys so you're just doing a simple lookup than having to retrieve any data.

Comment: `d.get(s)` and `s in d` perform two different operations. `d.get()` returns the value from the dictionary or a default value if it doesn't exist. `s in d` returns a boolean value.

Comment: `d.get(key)` also has to perform a method look-up and a function call, making it slower.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Can you answer this?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Can you help me what should I look into it? Sorry for being a noob.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava I cannot answer your question definitively. My guess is similar to Green Cloak Guy's: `d.get(s)` does a lot more work than `s in d`.

Comment: @iz_, `s in d` also looks up the `__contains__` method and calls it.

Comment: @kaya3 No, it does not have to perform a lookup for `__contains__` if called via `in`. You can confirm this with `dis`.

Comment: Oh, interesting, it only looks up `__contains__` if it's not a type with a C implementation of that method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html#dis.dis) method from the linked question:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('d.get(key)', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (d)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (get)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (key)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile('key in d', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (key)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (d)
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

we can clearly see that `d.get(key)` has to run one more step: the `LOAD_METHOD` step. Additionally, `d.get` must deal with more information: it has to:

1. check for the presence
2. if it was found, return the value
3. otherwise, return the specified default value (or `None` if no default was specified).

Also, from looking at the [C code for `in`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L3217) and the [C code for `.get`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2855), we can see that they are very similar.

```
int                                                           static PyObject * 
PyDict_Contains(PyObject *op, PyObject *key)                  dict_get_impl(PyDictObject *self, PyObject *key, PyObject *default_value)
{                                                             {
    Py_hash_t hash;                                               PyObject *val = NULL;
    Py_ssize_t ix;                                                Py_hash_t hash;
    PyDictObject *mp = (PyDictObject *)op;                        Py_ssize_t ix;                       
    PyObject *value;                                           

    if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(key) ||                             if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(key) ||                  
        (hash = ((PyASCIIObject *) key)->hash) == -1) {               (hash = ((PyASCIIObject *) key)->hash) == -1) {                             
        hash = PyObject_Hash(key);                                    hash = PyObject_Hash(key);        
        if (hash == -1)                                               if (hash == -1)
            return -1;                                                    return NULL;
    }                                                             }
    ix = (mp->ma_keys->dk_lookup)(mp, key, hash, &value);         ix = (self->ma_keys->dk_lookup) (self, key, hash, &val);                                         
    if (ix == DKIX_ERROR)                                         if (ix == DKIX_ERROR) 
        return -1;                                                    return NULL;
    return (ix != DKIX_EMPTY && value != NULL);                   if (ix == DKIX_EMPTY || val == NULL) {                        
}                                                                     val = default_value;
                                                                  }
                                                                  Py_INCREF(val);
                                                                  return val;
                                                              }
```

In fact, they are almost the same, but `.get` has more overhead and must return a value.

However, it seems that `d in key` will use a [faster method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e3d873d3bd0ef4708c4fa06b6cd6972574cb9af/Objects/dictobject.c#L3237) if the hash is known, while `d.get` recalculates the hash every time. Additionally, [`CALL_METHOD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f185a73249189bc3b75b4dc26e9ec2990a587b17/Python/ceval.c#L3444) and [`LOAD_METHOD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f185a73249189bc3b75b4dc26e9ec2990a587b17/Python/ceval.c#L3407) have much higher overhead than [`COMPARE_OP`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f185a73249189bc3b75b4dc26e9ec2990a587b17/Python/ceval.c#L2978), which performs one of the built-in boolean operations. Note that COMPARE_OP will simply jump to [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f185a73249189bc3b75b4dc26e9ec2990a587b17/Python/ceval.c#L5099).

Comment: Is `COMPARE_OP` not calling a method? `PyDict_Contains` has to do a similar check to `dict_get_impl`, and up the refcount of one of the boolean objects.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It is a method, but I was trying to say that the dis.dis didn't show a `LOAD_METHOD`. Edited.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The conclusion from the evidence you've presented seems to be that the time should be nearly identical.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added some information about the different `dis.dis` lines, and the amount of hashing done by each function.

Comment: Thank you for adding that. Now there's a clear story here

Answer (score 2):

**The time overhead is in calling a method explicitly**, as opposed to letting language constructs take care of it. We can demonstrate this with `timeit`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('"__name__" in x', 'x = globals()')
0.037103720999766665
>>> timeit.timeit('x.__contains__("__name__")', 'x = globals()')
0.07471312899997429
>>> timeit.timeit('x["__name__"]', 'x = globals()')
0.03828814600001351
>>> timeit.timeit('x.__getitem__("__name__")', 'x = globals()')
0.07529343100031838
>>> timeit.timeit('x.get("__name__")', 'x = globals()')
0.08261531900006958
```

I initially started trying to figure out the difference by looking at the source code for [`__contains__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2822) and [`.get()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2856), respectively, only to find that they're nearly identical except for `.get()` incrementing the object's reference count (which should be more or less negligible). Certainly there wasn't enough difference to explain the time difference you'd be seeing.

But, doing tests, we can see that actually using language constructs (`in` and `[]`) as opposed to the explicit method calls that they would turn into (`__contains__()` and `__getitem__()`, respectively), is a full 50% faster.

A full investigation would take a while and more effort than I care to spend, but I hypothesize this is due to some built-in speedups and skipped steps that the interpreter applies - using a language construct instead of explicitly calling a method narrows down the level of complexity that can be expected, and the interpreter could jump straight into the C code without the overhead of calling the method first.

---

As @rassar's answer demonstrates, this is, in fact, basically what happens.

Comment: Contains also increments a refcount BTW. It just happens outside the method.

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code do not do the same thing.  Notice how `self.memo` is set:

```
self.memo[s] = res
```

If `res` is `False`, the `if` statement for the `get` will fail while the `if` for `in` will succeed.