# Store past results of a function

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a function that takes in two arrays, does some calculation, and then returns a new array. The function is called maybe 60,000 times (or 500k, depending), where up to 25% of the times it is called, it is redoing a previous calculation.

```
prev_calc = {}
def arrayMagic(ar1,ar2):
    ar1_t = tuple(ar1)
    ar2_t = tuple(ar2)

    if (ar1_t,ar2_t) in prev_calc: 
        return prev_calc[(ar1_t,ar2_t)]
    #some somewhat, but not too expensive function
    res = magicCalc(ar1,ar2)

    prev_calc[(ar1_t,ar2_t)] = res

    return res
```

ar1 and ar2 are arrays of 3 floats each; for example: [1.1,1.2,2.2]
res is also an array of 3 floats.

The problem is that the tuple conversion and dictionary lookup happen to be very close to the time the `magicCalc()` function takes. Since this is the major bottleneck in my code, optimizing this would solve alot. The function is passed the two arrays, so I can't have them as an array already.

Is there a fast way to store past results of a function and return them?

Comment: `The problem is that the tuple conversion and dictionary lookup happen to be very close to the time the magicCalc() function takes.` What do you mean by this?

Comment: @information_interchange the amount of time magicCalc takes is not extremely long, but its not negligible.  Basically skipping the dictionary storage takes the same amount of time as after I implemented it. So if this is the fastest way to store results of the function, then I am done as both methods are close to the same speed. If there is any faster way, then I benefit.

Comment: Could you tell more about what `ar1` and `ar2` are? `numpy` arrays? How large?

Comment: How big are `ar1` and `ar2`?

Comment: @C.Nivs  sorry I updated, both are 3 floats. not numpy.

Comment: @MichaelButscher not numpy, part of it relies on ironpython

Comment: `retval = prev_calc.get((ar1, ar2)); if retval != None: return retval` would mean you aren't doing your lookups twice (once for the `in` condition, and a second time for the `return`). That said, I generally avoid choosing Python for performance-critical code.

Comment: Also -- if you haven't already run this code through a profiler, I'd strongly recommend it. Ideally, one that can keep an eye on what the garbage collector is doing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i will try the get method in the morning. i can't profile in the ironpython side, which i need as this is interfacing with an API. otherwise i agree about speed

Comment: There are some pretty good .net profilers out there. Sure, it's more work to read a profile of time spent in IronPython itself than it is to read one that describes your Python code's performance directly, but it may be at least as informative.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the get method is slower than checking if the key is in the dictionary since it is only there 25% of the time.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised -- it should require the same tree traversal either way, and `None` is a singleton, so there's no garbage collection load created by code that returns it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566331/why-does-dict-getkey-run-slower-than-dictkey

Comment: That's the case for CPython, but IronPython is running on a JITted engine; it should be able to optimize the lookup into the fast path; for that matter, I'd hope good JIT would be inlining the call itself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty quick...

```
d = dict()
l1 = [1.1,21.1,31.1,41.1,51.1]
l2 = [12.1,21.1,31.1,41.1,51.1]


def do(a1):
    cacheKey = str(a1) 
    if cacheKey in d:
        print("Read from cache")
        return d[cacheKey]
    else:
        print("calc and cache result")
        d[cacheKey] = sum(a1)
        return d[cacheKey]

print(do(l1))
print(do(l2))
print(do(l1))
```

Comment: Measured how? The `print()`s are going to be slower than anything else here, slow enough to dominate any timings measured.

Comment: The print statements are only for example. The real issue here is how best to hash an array in order to cache it. Given that there are only 3 floats in the array, converting it to a string shouldn't be that expensive. No actual measurement was taken.

Comment: If you want to assert that `str(somelist)` is faster than `tuple(somelist)`, benchmarks are in order to back that up. I would be *extremely* surprised if it were true.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/gCZahY -- `tuple(l)` is more than 20x faster than `str(l)`.