# Cannot get text of a span attribute using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get from the following

```
<span id="SkuNumber" itemprop="identifier" content="sku:473768" data-nodeid="176579" class="product-code col-lg-4 col-md-4">ΚΩΔ. 473768</span></div>
```

the value of data-nodeid 
I did the following

```
price_nodes = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'SkuNumber'})
datanode = price_nodes.select_one('span[data-nodeid]')
```

But I get "None" 
How can I fix this? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `price_nodes` is correctly fill

i.e. `price_nodes` =

```
<span id="SkuNumber" itemprop="identifier" content="sku:473768" data-nodeid="176579" class="product-code col-lg-4 col-md-4">ΚΩΔ. 473768</span>
```

You just have to do this:

```
datanode = price_nodes.get('data-nodeid')
```

Full code should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = '<div><span id="SkuNumber" itemprop="identifier" content="sku:473768" data-nodeid="176579" class="product-code col-lg-4 col-md-4">ΚΩΔ. 473768</span></div>'
page = soup(html, 'html.parser')
price_nodes = page.find('span', {'id': 'SkuNumber'})
datanode = price_nodes.get('data-nodeid')
```

Comment: Is price_nodes['data-nodeid'] faster than price_nodes.get('data-nodeid') ?

Comment: As said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36566435/2437141, `get()` seems to be a little bit slower (but not so much), but it allows you to define default value if value is not present, like `get('data-nodeid', 'N/A')`

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span id="SkuNumber" itemprop="identifier" content="sku:473768" data-nodeid="176579" class="product-code col-lg-4 col-md-4">ΚΩΔ. 473768</span></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

price_nodes = soup.find('span', attrs={'id': 'SkuNumber'})
print(price_nodes['data-nodeid'])
```